# How to enable view transitions in an Angular 17 app with NgModules?

Tags: angular, ng-modules, view-transitions-api

The Angular 17 blog post says:

You can add this feature to your app today by configuring it in the router’s provider declaration during bootstrap:

```js
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withViewTransitions()),
  ]
});
```

However, I'm using NgModules, so my main.ts bootstrap looks like this:

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

And the RouterModule is imported in the each of the modules, like:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
```

So, no `providers` and no `provideRouter()` method. Where do I need to add `withViewTransitions()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You you can do it with it `forRoot`. You need to set this up at the application level.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([ /* routes...*/], {enableViewTransitions: true}],
```

This is defined in [`ExtraOptions`](https://angular.dev/api/router/ExtraOptions).